# How to add custom icons in the Leading Parameter in ListTitle

Tags: flutter

I want to add custom png icon images in the `leading` of a `ListTitle`. How do I go about doing this, I've already uploaded the image in the images folder and added the dependencies via pubspec.yaml

Here is the code with the default icons, I need to change the bubble_chart icon to a custom image icon:

```
            new Divider(),
            new ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.bubble_chart),
              title: new Text('About the App'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AboutTheApp()),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: you can try this - leading: Image.asset('images/name.png'),

Comment: Works great, is there a chance to have the same scale as the icons or is it relative to the image size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can Use Height,Width & Scale to Alter the Image size.

```
leading: Image.asset('images/imagename.png',scale:1.0,height:10.0,width:10.0,),
```